# Azure Bot and Webchat: There was an error sending this message to your bot

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-bot-service, azureportal

I created a bot, deployed it on azure via GitHub actions and tested in the emulator, everything works fine, but when i try to connect the channel "Webchat" i keep receive errors like

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadGateway
```

but it kinda changes randomly without me changing anything. Of course i set messaging endpoint in the Configuration tab (The same as i was testing in the emulator, https://appservicename.azurewebsites.net/api/messages) and the check for Enable Streaming Endpoint.
The question is: how to i fix this or how can i even find a solution when the errors are not always the same?

UPDATE More info: I made my app from basic code, i have my

```
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});
```

ID is taken in Azure Bot Configuration Tab.
Password is created in App Secrets Key Vault, manually created under Secrets.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: When you created the Azure bot resource, did you create this as a single-tenant, multi-tenant, or as a user-assigned managed identity?

Answer (score 0):

According to this MSFT [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), this can happen if you use a self-signed certificate.

If the chat window indicates one or more errors, click the error(s) for additional information. Among the most common issues are:

- The bot's endpoint is specified incorrectly in the emulator settings. Ensure that the URL contains the correct port number and the correct path  at the end of the URL.
- A bot endpoint that starts with https is specified in the emulator settings. The endpoint on localhost should start with http.
- The Microsoft App ID field and/or the Microsoft App Password fields in the emulator settings do not contain valid values. Both fields should be filled in, with each field containing the corresponding data.
- Security has not been enabled for the bot. Verify that the bot configuration settings specify values for both app ID and password.

Also, try modifying the App Service's Protocol Setting. If you used Bot Composer to deploy your bot, you'll notice two App Services in the resource group: one with a 'qna' suffix and the other without. Choose the one that does not end in 'qna.'

`Select the App Service` --> `TLS/SSL settings` --> `HTTPS Only` --> `On`

References - [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144699/there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bot-test-in-web-chat), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467234/there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bot-http-status-code-notfound), [Ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435491/test-in-web-chat-typing-message-returns-not-found-http-status-code-after-deplo).

Comment: Already tried TLS/SSL settings

I made my app from basic code, i have my 
`const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});`

ID is taken in Azure Bot Configuration Tab
Password is created in App Secrets Key Vault, manually created under Secrets.

What im doing wrong?